# Refresh Page upon React Component Update

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have few React Components in my app which sends ajax calls. All works fine except one thing. I want to refresh the page when a particular component gets updated. So I used `location.reload()` in `componentWillReceiveProps` method. Though it works, unfortunately the whole page reloads whenever a component gets an update instead of just the component that has `location.reload()` code.

Why this is happening and how can I prevent / solve this?

*Update and clarification:*  Thanks for the answers. I'm very much aware that state change re-renders the component. This is not a standalone React app and refreshing page is a requirement.

This react app is part of WP settings page which is tabbed one. One tab of settings is a react app. Upon enabling a button, corresponding tab should be visible and that needs page refresh (as it is not react, but WP backend code).

My question is If I add `location.reload()` in `componentWillReceiveProps` method of a single component, then why other components also refreshes page even though they don't have such code. Is `componentWillReceiveProps` a static method that is shared between all components? Why does other component state changes picks up `location.reload()` and refresh pages?

Comment: I think you should be using state instead of reloading the component.

Comment: How does your `particular component get updated`?

Comment: @Venkat Raj N did one of these answers solve your problem? If so, you should click the big green check mark next to the answer that solved your problem

Answer (score 0):

use a state variable and whenever you get any changes then setState which will only update your component instead of updating the whole page.
 for more reference see this:https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html

Answer (score 0):

wrap location.reload() with some condition (eg. if block) and choose that condition according to your component state change, don't write location.reload() directly because it will run for any state change that passed to that component.